Why is the "New Flutter Project" option missing in Android Studio Ladybug after updating?
After updating to Android Studio Ladybug (2024.2.1 Patch 3), I noticed that the "New Flutter Project" option is missing. I’ve already tried the following steps to resolve this issue:

Verified that the Flutter and Dart plugins are installed and
up-to-date.

Restarted Android Studio and invalidated caches.

Uninstalled and reinstalled the Flutter and Dart plugins.


Even after these steps, the Flutter project option does not appear in the New Project dialogue.
Has anyone else experienced this issue with Android Studio Ladybug? How can I restore the "New Flutter Project" option?

Huh.  Works for me.  What does "flutter doctor -v" say?

The "New Flutter Project" option missing in Android Studio Ladybug may result from plugin or SDK misconfigurations. Ensure the Flutter and Dart plugins are installed and enabled under File > Settings > Plugins. Verify the Flutter SDK path in File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter and restart Android Studio. If the issue persists, reinstall the plugins and invalidate caches.

Both these plugins are uninstalled and installed multiple times.


Check Flutter SDK Path:
File > Settings > Languages & Frameworks > Flutter
Enable Flutter Plugin
File > Settings > Plugins
Search for "Flutter" and ensure it is enabled. Disable and re-enable it if needed
Manually Configure Flutter
Using flutter doctor
Reset Android Studio
Close Android Studio and delete the configuration files
Windows: Delete %USERPROFILE%.AndroidStudio2024.2
macOS: Delete ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio2024.2
Relaunch Android Studio and reinstall the plugins.
Test on a Fresh Instal
Uninstall Android Studio completely and reinstall it.

